# Does iCloud web mail not have an "organize by conversation" feature?

Tags: icloud, email

I'm trying to use iCloud email in the web interface. I'm not used to all the emails in a thread/chain/conversation appearing separately in the inbox. I don't see a setting to control that. Does it have one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iCloud Mail doesn't have a feature "organize by conversation".